# How to add minutes to to a date in laravel

Tags: laravel, time

There are few ways that I can do this using PHP but I could not find a way to do that using laravel specific way.

I have a time that is coming from database in below format: `Y:M:s`

ex: `05:15:00`

This is what I want to do:

add **30 minutes** to that date, according to above example result should be: `05:45:00`

Below is my current code and I want to add 30min to `$endTime`:

```
//get database value according to selected date
$allocatedDateQuery = DB::table('appointments')->where('date', $request->date)->get();

//loop throug every record to get time
foreach ($allocatedDateQuery as $value) {
    $time = $value->time;
    $endTime = $time;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just got a perfect solution [from here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon).

Use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) extention to simply acheive that.

What you have to do is `parse` your time to `Carbon` object and then you can use `addMinutes()` to do that and then you can `format()` if you want:

```
foreach ($allocatedDateQuery as $value) {
    $time = Carbon::parse($value->time);
    $endTime = $time->addMinutes(30);
    $allocateValidateMessage .= Carbon::parse($value->time)->format('H:i') . ' - ' . $endTime->format('H:i') . '  ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually I use [php's date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), you can give this a try

```
Date("Y:M:s", strtotime("30 minutes", strtotime($value->time))
```

That is converting your time into a string, adding 30minutes to it and converting it to the date format of your desire

Comment: Allow me to suggest to use the ORM to retrieve the data (e.g.   Appointsments::where('date', $request->date)->get();) . and using accessors to simplify your needs  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you are grabbing the date from the database I am assuming you are also using Eloquent to query from the database.

You can use [Eloquent Mutator Method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators) in your Database Modal Class to mutate the data like this:

```
    public function getAppointmentsAttribute($value) {
        return Date("Y:M:s", strtotime("30 minutes", strtotime($value->time)));
    }
```

You can even add another attribute without mutating the original value using Attribute assignments as well. This method caches your query and reduces database calls. Since you do not need to run local loops on the record your code is much cleaner.